# WebRequest.GetResponseAsync() doesn't receives response if i disconnect the wifi and reconnect it

Tags: c#

- I am making a request to a device.
- That device is supposed to process the request and then send
  response.
- Now if while waiting for the response, if i disconnect the device and
  device is now not in my network and reconnect it before the device
  sends response.

> the response is not being received at all.

## I want to receive the response after a successful re connection.

```
WebRequest webReq = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            webReq.Timeout = InfiniteTime;
            using (WebResponse webResp = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = webResp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Validate XML to Genius XSD class
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(resultType);
                        return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am assuming an exception is being thrown. You'd need to put some retry handling logic in e.g. Transient Fault handling. Take a look at the Polly library.

Comment: No. I didn't get any exception when the connection is active throughout. If connection is active then the response is received and processed but if i disconnect and reconnect than my application waits for a long time but do not receives any response as i have set requestTimeOUT to infinite

Comment: Then don't set the timeout to infinite. It's a bad idea anyway to wait infinitely on something.

Comment: Actually its a card payment device and while it processes a payment request, we have to wait for the response. And we dont want to bind the customer to process the request in a fixed time frame. Also, If i have a transaction on the device then no retries can be made as the device has to be in idle screen state to process the request and if we already have a request ongoing than we will not be able to make request further. I suppose that i need to listen the response of the original request anyhow. :(